# Como listar na listView os resultados do MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Estrutura do Código

Nesta função abaixo eu tentando pegar o conteúdo do banco de dados MySql e passando para um `List<BDependente> lDep` na linha onde esta `facade.listDependente(bDep);`

**Método Funcionário**

```
        lvDependente.Columns.Add("Nome", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvDependente.Columns.Add("Parentesco", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvDependente.Columns.Add("Nascimento", 130, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        lDep = facade.listDependente(bDep);            
        foreach (BDependente bDepe in lDep) {
            string[] row = {bDepe.Nome, bDepe.Grau_parentesco, bDepe.Data_nascimento };
            lvDependente.Items.Add(row);
        }
        lvDependente.View = View.Details;
```

O Resultado disso é que sai apenas o ultimo registro do banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para popular um listview utilize desta forma:

```
    foreach (BDependente bDepe in lDep)
    {
        ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(bDepe.Nome);
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(bDepe.Grau_parentesco);
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(bDepe.Data_nascimento);
        lvDependente.Items.Add(lvItem);
    }
```

Comment: Implementei a sua dica mas o resultado sai da maneira não esperada ! Ele está trazendo apenas o último resultado.

Comment: O problema pode estar aqui:`lDep = facade.listDependente(bDep);`

Comment: esse método listDependente é um método de consulta no Banco, o problema deve ser lá ? ou é no List<>

Comment: Implementei a sua dica mas o resultado sai da maneira não esperada ! Ele está trazendo apenas o último resultado, o resultado deveria ser:

`Ikaro       | Sobrinho(a) | 2016-04-13
 Ikaro Sales | Neto(a)     | 2016-04-05`


**Como está saindo:**

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F1DyP.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7pVWb.png

Comment: Verifica se o conteúdo da variavel `lDep` está correto e se não possui dados repetidos

Comment: Eu estou achando que o problema está na consulda do banco

Comment: Ok ! Desde já muito obrigado Tiago